# Appending File in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am taking a Word RTF file and then replacing data within in and then writing it to a specific folder and appending the requestID to the file name.  That part works great.  However, my client also want to be able to print each word document that is generated at the smae time if there are multiple records.

For this I am reading the same RTF file, replaceing the data within it and then writing to a seperate file that I am attempting to append too within the loop, however it isn't working.  I am only getting one record of the query.

```
        <cfloop query="checklistData">

        <cffile action="read" file="#request.filePath#\_reports\fileChecklist.rtf" variable="rtf">

        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%PROGRAM%",#rqst_activity#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%DLA%",#DLA#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%SPS%",#SPS#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%ECAT%",#ECAT#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%MILSTRIP%",#MILSTRIP#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%TDPNUM%",#tdp_nbr#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%DTRQST%",#DateFormat(dt_tdp_rcvd,'M/DD/YYYY')#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%DTCMPT%",#DateFormat(dt_tdp_cmplt,'M/DD/YYYY')#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%DTDEL%",#DateFormat(rqsted_delivery_dt,'M/DD/YYYY')#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%UIC%",#DoDAAC#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%COMMAND%",#COMMAND#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%DTPRINT%",#DateFormat(NOW(),'M/DD/YYYY')#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%NSN%",#nsn_id_rqsted#)>
        <cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%NOMEN%",#nsn_nomenclature#)>


        <cfset directoryCheck = "#request.filePath#\requests\documents\#checklistData.id_rqst#">

        <cfif directoryExists(directoryCheck)>
            <cffile action="write" file="#request.filePath#\requests\documents\#checklistData.id_rqst#\fileChecklist_#checklistData.id_rqst#.doc" output="#rtf#" nameconflict="overwrite">
        <cfelse>
            <cfdirectory action="create" directory="#directoryCheck#">
            <cffile action="write" file="#request.filePath#\requests\documents\#checklistData.id_rqst#\fileChecklist_#checklistData.id_rqst#.doc" output="#rtf#" nameconflict="overwrite">
        </cfif>

        <cffile action="append" file="#request.filePath#\requests\documents\fileChecklistGroup_#ARGUMENTS.groupID#.rtf" output="#rtf#">

    </cfloop>

    <cfif NOT LEN('checklistData.groupID')>
        <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="filename=#request.filePath#\requests\documents\#requestID#\fileChecklist_#requestID#.doc" />  
        <cfcontent type="application/msword" file="#request.filePath#\requests\documents\#requestID#\fileChecklist_#requestID#.doc">
    <cfelse>
        <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="filename=#request.filePath#\requests\documents\fileChecklistGroup_#groupID#.rtf" />  
        <cfcontent type="application/msword" file="#request.filePath#\requests\documents\fileChecklistGroup_#groupID#.rtf">
    </cfif>

    <cfabort>
```

And then I am asking to open the file at the end.  Thanks in advance for an help!

Comment: Your question is unclear. The text says "print all docs", but the code is for a file download. Which one is it? The only way to download multiple files in a single request is to add the files to a .zip, and present the .zip file for downloading. If you mean merge the individual rtf files into one *big* file, it is not as simple as concatenating the text together. Do a search on "merge rtf".

Comment: don't understand the meaning of the cffile append tag

Comment: @Leigh Thanks Leigh, I'll check out merge rtf.  And yes, that is what I meant.  Sorry if I was unclear.